# Globally exclude cloned items from index?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7

I am looking for an elegant way to exclude cloned items from my web index. I am having items appear as duplicates in my search results. I'd prefer it if only the original items appear and no clones at all.

Some possible solutions that come to mind are to:

1. **Create a `Global Item Boosting Rule` to drastically lower the boost value if the item's `_Source` field is not empty.** This is not preferred as it only lowers the score and does not remove the clones from the search results.
2. **Exclude the cloned items in every query that I perform using an extended Where clause.** This is also not preferred as it means that I need to remember to include this clause on all queries. Furthermore, the cloned items still remain in the index.

Sitecore v7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach is like this:

```cs
public class InboundIndexFilter : InboundIndexFilterProcessor
{
    public override void Process(InboundIndexFilterArgs args)
    {
        var item = args.IndexableToIndex as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        if (item != null && (!item.Item.Versions.IsLatestVersion() || item.Item.IsClone))
        {
            args.IsExcluded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

It skips clones and non-latest versions. Then I updated the corresponding pipeline settings:

```xml
 <indexing.filterIndex.inbound>
    <processor type="XY.InboundIndexFilter, X.Y.Z"/>
 </indexing.filterIndex.inbound>
```

[More about inbound filters](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-inbound-and-outbound-filter-pipelines.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom crawler and add logic into that to exclude items that are cloned.
The approach I'm thinking of would be to create a class that inherits from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler` and override the `DoAdd()` method.
Something like this:

```cs
protected override void DoAdd(IProviderUpdateContext context, SitecoreIndexableItem indexable)
{
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) context, "context");
    Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) indexable, "indexable");

    if (!indexable.Item.IsClone)
    {
        base.DoAdd(context, indexable);
    }
}
```

Then you need to setup your crawler config to use your custom crawler.
In the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.<Lucene/Solr>.Index.<databasename>.config` file you define which crawlers are used.
You need to update the `contentSearch/configuration/indexes/locations/crawler` element and point to you class there.

Comment: I'd just like to add that you might want to override IsExcludedFromIndex instead. It is a bit more saying for what you are trying to achieve. However both solutions will work.

Comment: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler` appears to be sealed class, is there another crawler class that I can inherit from?

Comment: Try inheriting from Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Crawlers.LuceneDatabaseCrawler. I remember the Sc7 Dev team telling us we should use that. I blogged about the indexing mechanism here: http://www.partechit.nl/nl/blog/2013/04/sitecore-7-in-depth-indexing-mechanics

Comment: You can use SitecoreItemCrawler, but need to update to a newer revision of Sitecore. The class being sealed is a mistake and is fixed in revision 131127 of Sitecore 7 and in Sitecore 7.1 as well.

Comment: Can we remove an existing item from the index based on some conditions? Any specific even handler for that or any property i need to set?