# Sitecore 7.2 and SOLR: exclude clones from web index

Tags: solr, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I'm trying to exclude all clones from Sitecore's web index. I've created a custom crawler inheriting from `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler` overriding the `IsExcludedFromIndex` method with the following code:

```cs
protected override bool IsExcludedFromIndex(SitecoreIndexableItem indexable, bool checkLocation)
{
    if (indexable.Item["Hide from Search"] == "1")
        return true;
    if (indexable.Item.IsClone)
        return true;
    return base.IsExcludedFromIndex(indexable, checkLocation);
}
```

My `"Hide from Search"` field works: any items with that field set are not included in the web index. However, the `indexable.Item.IsClone` is never true, and all "clones" remain in the web index.

When I run the master index against this crawler, the `IsClone` is true for each clone and they are not included in the index. I suspect it works for master and not for the web index because clones are expanded on publishing targets ([as noted by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Enable-Default-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx)).

Apologies if this question is considered a duplicate of [Globally exclude cloned items from index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646719/globally-exclude-cloned-items-from-index) - the solution there did not work for me, and I'm using SOLR (vs Lucene) and on a newer version of Sitecore, so I believe this may be a separate issue.

So, how can I exclude all clones from a SOLR index of a Sitecore 7.2 web (publish target) database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote in your question, `IsClone` property is not relevant for items which are published, cause Sitecore clears the value of `__Source` field.

That's why there is no out of the box method to determine whether the item from the web database was a clone or not.

What you can use is the solution proposed by John West in his blog post [Identify Cloned Items Sitecore ASPNET CMS Publishing Target Databases](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/02/Identify-Cloned-Items-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Publishing-Target-Databases.aspx"). In nutshell, you need to add your processor to the publishing pipeline, and save the value of the `__Source` field in another custom field or at least store boolean value in your custom `Is Cloned` field.

Then you can use your approach, just instead of checking `IsClone` you need to check whether new custom field is not empty.

Comment: While a PITA, this seems to be the solution that works. Thanks.